# Multer and Callbacks issue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, multer

Since two days I tried to solve an issue when I upload an image on Vue Js. 
Everything is good except I have a blank squire with the good url for the image and I need to refresh the page to see the image. It's like the image is corrupted or the download not ended before I refresh manually.

I read the multer documentation, I check my callbacks but I don't understand why I have this issue. This is the relevant code from my server:

**Back-end**

```
const multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: '../client/static/images/uploads',
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
             callback(null, raw.toString('hex')+path.extname(file.originalname))
        });
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage:storage})

router.post('/uploadPic', upload.single('userPic'), function(req, res) {

    if (!req.file) {
        return res.send({success: false})
    } else {
        profile.addPic(req.body.id, req.body.isProfile, req.file.filename, callback => {
            var fs = require('fs');
            if (fs.existsSync('../client/static/images/uploads/'+req.file.filename)) {
                res.send({success: true})
            }
        })
    }
})
```

**Front-End**

Step 1 : I collect the Formdata on my component and when it's done I emit the data to my main component

```
upload () {
      this.feedback = ''
      var format = this.images.addFile.type

      function checkFormat (format) {
        switch (format) {
          case 'image/png': return true
          case 'image/jpeg': return true
          case 'image/jpg': return true
          default: return false
        }
      }
      function addFile (images, id, count, callback) {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('userPic', images, images.name)
        formData.append('id', id)
        if (!count) { formData.append('isProfile', 1) }
        callback(formData)
      }

      if (!checkFormat(format)) {
        this.feedback = 'Format de fichier invalide'
      } else if (this.images.count === 5) {
        this.feedback = 'Vous ne pouvez pas avoir plus de 5 photos'
      } else {
        addFile(this.images.addFile, this.userId, this.images.count, callback => {
          callback = this.$emit('updatePic', 'upload', callback)
        })
      }
    }
```

Step 2 : I receive the event and with a switch if I have upload I go on this function who call the Front services for a communication between the back and the front.

```
Pictures.uploadPic(data, callback => {
            callback = this.getPic(this.user.id)
          })
```

Step 3 : Pictures.uploadPic is a service who go to the back with this:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  uploadPic (formData, callback) {
    return Api().post('profile/uploadPic', formData, callback).then(function (response) {
      callback(response.data)
    })
  },
```

**UPDATE**
With setTimeout I see the problem. I put the path of the image before the image is saved in my file. Indeed the file is saved on disk only when I enter in the router post upload Pic. Navin recommend me to use next from multer but the problem is still the same.

```
router.post('/uploadPic', upload.single('userPic'), (req, res, next) => {
// my previous code to put in the db the pathname
}
```

Comment: Hi Brugher, welcome to SO. To help with answering your question, could you include the code from the frontend where the issue is occurring. Additionally, a bit more detail on what happens currently and what you would like to happen would be helpful!

Comment: @HenryWoody Thank you for the reply. I added more details and the front end code. I also add few lines about the issue... But it's hard to describe... When I upload and then I launch getPictures the <img src> is good on the page but the image is empty like she is broken. I need to manually refresh to see the picture just after an upload.

Comment: I think issue is with your `router.post('/uploadPic', upload.single('userPic'), function(req, res) {` as upload.single must be a function taking three params as input `req, res, next` or some additional for file too, and from there will call `next` function so can go to `function (req, res) {`

Comment: @NAVIN thank you I try this in few moments but do you know how use next? I put before setTimeout everywhere and indeed I have a problem when I enter in my last function the file is still not saved on the disk.

Comment: @Brugher After file upload is complete inside `upload.single()`. As this function is not shared so don't know what's going inside it.

Comment: @NAVIN I shared everything in the backend code. const upload = multer({storage:storage}) an single is a basic usage of the middleware.